# Cocoa Touch - Upsidedown Buttons and Text

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm making a 2 player game where you play on either side of the iPhone and I need to have upside down buttons. Any ideas on flipping them around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to set the `transform` property of `UIView`. You can do many types of transforms, but a rotation of 180 degrees will flip it for you.

```
// angle is radians, so convert degrees to radians
float degrees = 180.0;
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( degrees / 180.0 * M_PI );
```

Comment: In dont want to rotate the whole view. Could I replace `view.transform` with my button/label name?

Comment: shorty876: Pay attention to superclasses. Buttons and labels are views just as much as the view your view controller owns directly is.